# Change Assign ID Value of an element to the data attribute of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several HTML link elements, which all have a unique number ID.

These are all stored in a wrapper, which uses a data attribute called "data-color".

When the user clicks on the links, I want the data-color to take on the number ID of the link.

I thought I could use data(), but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dLQHs/2/).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" data-color="01">

<span>Color Box</span>

<a class="ThumbnailBox" href="#" id="02">02</a>
<a class="ThumbnailBox" href="#" id="03">03</a>
<a class="ThumbnailBox" href="#" id="04">04</a>
<a class="ThumbnailBox" href="#" id="05">05</a>
<a class="ThumbnailBox" href="#" id="06">06</a>

</div>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".ThumbnailBox").click(function () {
            selectedcolor = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#wrapper').data('datacolor', selectedcolor);

        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this, you don't have to use data- to use it

```
$(".ThumbnailBox").click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').data('color', this.id);
});
```

to change the value in dom than use attr

```
$('#wrapper').attr('data-color', this.id);
```

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this here, but it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/T7GUz/1/

Answer (score 1):

you just try this code it working fine..

```
$(".ThumbnailBox").click(function () {
selectedcolor = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(selectedcolor)
$('#wrapper').attr('data-color', selectedcolor);
});
```

Here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dLQHs/3/